# JSON Clarification

Tags: php, jquery, json, csv, callback

Can someone please help me breakdown the statement below... base_url was originally pointing to what I can only assume was a directory that contained a .csv file.

Given that I have a custom .csv file on my server, I changed the address of the base_url, but I'm not seeing any data.

I have about a million questions around this with a VERY SHORT deadline. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW... I've looked through the JQUERY site another sites to try and understand.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$.getJSON(this.base_url+"?callback=?", {cmd:"getMakes", year:"2009"}, function(data) {

   //The 'data' variable contains all response data.
   var makes = data.Makes;
   for (var i = 0; i < makes.length; i++)
   {
       //You can now do what you like with the response data
       alert(makes[i].make_display);
   }
});
```

Comment: Usually you'd need some kind of web server to actually serve up your "CSV" content. You wouldn't get that content from a raw CSV file as they have no knowledge of HTTP, it's just a flat file.

Comment: Right.. I have my .csv file loaded on my server. So what do you mean by "serve up"? I know the .csv file is simply a flat file, I need to use a similar approach like the code I posted to GET the data out of the .csv file and into <select>

Comment: Ok, something has to be servicing your GET request. Perhaps it is Apache, IIS, A N Other web server. Some piece of software is taking your GET (with parameters on the querystring), possibly reading the CSV file and then sending back the data in JSON format.

Comment: post your base URL, it could shed some light on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses.. Here's what I'm trying to do. This link points to a .csv file, [link](http://www.carqueryapi.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2012/01/car_query_models_full_sample.csv). Now, [link](http://www.carqueryapi.com/js/carquery.0.3.3.js), contains the base_url variable, which I redirected to my site.. where I'm using Apache as my web server. My hosting provider is through Hostmonsters.. but I'm not even at the point where I'm trying to load this publicly; as I'm still in test.

Comment: You're using somebody else's API, which probably points to a proprietary service. Looking at the code, it isn't directly pointing to the CSV, it's doing a call to get parts of it. You're probably going to have to write your own lightweight REST style service to get the results based on the criteria passed in by the API (e.g. getTrims by makeId etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the syntax of the script and the context it is being used in, I will throw it out there to say, 'this.base_url' is not supposed to be a .CSV file.

First, `$.getJSON`, will set a GET request to your webserver. If it was just a GET request for a CSV file, it would make all the sense, as you are GETting the CSV file. But, the JSON keyword was added, meaning you are expecting a properly formatted JSON response to your GET request.

Secondly, you are adding GET data, `?cmd=getMakes&year=2009`. A CSV file by nature is a flat file on the filesystem. It is not a smart file, meaning it is not driven by logic, unless you do a redirect within your .htaccess file or MIME type modifications.

You are probably looking for a file other than a .csv. Some framework allow you to interpret a link such as `http://domain.com/api/function`, which looks like a url with the extension omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. that changed my course of action to now try and build my custom REST style service; as suggested by Jeff Watkins.